# Running latex in interactive mode from texstudio

Tags: editors, texstudio

I am using TeXStudio as LaTeX editor. Can I configure TeXStudio such that it can run commands in terminal in interactive mode. I have found some solution from this site: http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/393/
but for Windows.

I am using TeXStudio 2.6 in Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: An Alternative: Open Nautilus file browser from the folder consisting `.tex` file and  `Open in Terminal` from `File menu` of Nautilus

Comment: The maintainer of TeXStudio recommends compiling with the standard cli of the operating system. Seems to be the most reasonable way, but isn't covered here on TeX.SX.